# clarifai api with dot net Web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a web API in .net using `C#` and I want to call `clarifai` api to get image tag.

How can I do this?

> Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Here's an updated answer that shows you how to send an image from your local machine to Clarifai's API. This example uses version 2 of the API. If you try to use version 1 you will get a status error of 429. This is to encourage people to use version 2. This is discussed at https://community.clarifai.com/t/request-was-throttled/402.

The following example is a method that takes a stream. This stream is later converted to a byte array and encoded in base 64. This encoded data is sent in JSON format to Clarifai's API.

```
public void ClarifaiTagging(Stream imageStream)
{
    const string ACCESS_TOKEN = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";
    const string CLARIFAI_API_URL = "https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/{model}/outputs";

    // Convert the stream to a byte array and convert it to base 64 encoding
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageStream.CopyTo(ms);
    string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Set the authorization header
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + ACCESS_TOKEN);

        // The JSON to send in the request that contains the encoded image data
        // Read the docs for more information - https://developer.clarifai.com/guide/predict#predict
        HttpContent json = new StringContent(
            "{" +
                "\"inputs\": [" +
                    "{" +
                        "\"data\": {" +
                            "\"image\": {" +
                                "\"base64\": \"" + encodedData + "\"" +
                            "}" +
                       "}" +
                    "}" +
                "]" +
            "}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        // Send the request to Clarifai and get a response
        var response = client.PostAsync(CLARIFAI_API_URL, json).Result;

        // Check the status code on the response
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // End here if there was an error
            return null;
        }

        // Get response body
        string body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();

        Debug.Write(body);
    }
}
```

Hope this helped.

**EDIT:**

To use v2 of the Clarifai API to tag an image from a URL simply use the following.

```
HttpContent json = new StringContent(
    "{" +
        "\"inputs\": [" +
            "{" +
                "\"data\": {" +
                    "\"image\": {" +
                        "\"url\": \"" + yourUrlHere + "\"" +
                    "}" +
                "}" +
            "}" +
        "]" +
    "}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Full documentation for the Clarifai API can be found at https://www.clarifai.com/developer/guide/.

Comment: Is there a v2 ?&url= version similar to @Cassidy Williams' answer?

Comment: @kjhf of course. Simply replace the line "\"base64\": \"" + encodedData + "\"" + with "\"url\": \"" + yourUrlHere+ "\"" +

Comment: Also, I started writing a C# library a while back to handle a lot of this work. Just ask and I'll put it on GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

This project might be useful for you:
https://github.com/codingbrent/clarifai-nsfw-detection-csharp/blob/master/httpclartest/Program.cs#L33

Long story short, you have to construct a URL:

```
string url = "http://api.clarifai.com/v1/tag/?&url=" + your_image_url + "&access_token=" + your_access_token
```

Your access token will come from your Client ID and Client Secret.  You can then run the following to make a GET request:

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient()
byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData(url);
string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);
```

And then all you'd have to do is parse the JSON from there.

Comment: And what if we want to use image from our disk?

Comment: @M.SherazLeo I've answered that below.

Comment: This answer uses version 1 of the API. I suggest using version 2 instead.